# What strategy to better articulate myself when summarising technical details

Tags: teamwork, communication, presentation

I am required to speak at daily stand ups, change review and architect reference group meetings.

I usually find that I speak too quickly, include too much or not enough details, or go back and forth without a narrative. However I always understand the material and write well structured emails and technical documentation.

What strategies can I use summaries my thoughts and better convey technical details?

Comment: "However I always [...] write well structured emails and technical documentation." Would it work to write down what you'll say before you say it?

Comment: I was looking for something like "if your not sure, describe past present and future...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a short note in advance which points you need to mention in what order. Doesn't need to be detailed at all. That should help a lot with keeping your speaking reasonably structured and on point.

If you still find yourself getting into too much detail then that's a habit you need to untrain - as is speaking too fast. Practice it when you're alone by describing some technical requirement to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and consciously force yourself to speak slowly and not veer into details. Then practice some more.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Michael Borgwardt answer.

A way to *untrain* the habit of speaking too fast or provide with too many info is planning the speech as if you were to speak to children or to your wife. Or anybody else unfamiliar with the subject.

When I have to do so, I force myself to sum up every subject of my script in no more than 1 or 2 phrases. Each phrase must lead to the next subject as if it was a natural process.

If you ever have spoken to children, you probably realised that they get distracted quickly, unless you speak to them with the right cadence and with a fairly plain language.

You will know when they need more info when they do what they do best, to ask *Why, When, How, Who or What*.

The same applies to the standups. Whoever needs more details, will ask you for them. Then, if you don't feel able to respond with a short answer, tell him/her to wait for the standup to end.